# ElementNotFoundInGetRequest: None --> Element was not found in the get request

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using a google translator into my code

```
translator = GoogleTranslator(source="de", target="en")
```

creating a function to translate

```
def translate_text(text):
    """Translate for columns."""
    try:
        return translator.translate(text)
    except ValueError:
        return text
```

when i try to apply the function on marketing_data dataframe i am getting an error

```
marketing_daily_data["MOTIV"] = marketing_daily_data["MOTIV"].apply(translate_text)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6doc.png)